# Textmate rails bundle

Tags: text-editing, textmate, ruby-on-rails

Normally when working inside a Ruby on Rails view file, I can hit `CTRL + SHIFT + .` to get open/close tags for rails like so:

```
<%= selection %>
```

I'm not sure how, but yesterday this functionality stopped working.
I reinstalled the Ruby on Rails bundle for Textmate but alas, it did not help.
Can anybody speculate might have happened and how I could fix it/reset to original settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The snippet to insert `<%= selection %>` is actually part of the Ruby TextMate bundle not the Ruby on Rails bundle. You might want to reinstall the Ruby bundle.

If that doesn't work go into the Bundle Editor and look at the snippets under the Ruby bundle.